# Using strtotime in QUERY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to use strtotime in a sql query (php) like this:

```
select * from USERS WHERE nickname = '$nickname'
     AND strtotime(COLUMNTIME) < time()");
```

Columntime is a a field in the table USERS.

1. Selecting if nickname is var nickname then
2. Only selecting if the COLUMNTIME is less earlier then the time now. 
   COLUMNTIME in table USERS is a timestamp.

I get an error when i do it like above:

> Warning: ... expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ....

Comment: What data type does columntime have?

Comment: If you get that error, it means you're not checking the result of `mysql_query()` to see if it failed. You need to print `mysql_error()` when that happens.

Comment: @juergend He wrote "is a timestamp"

Comment: `strtotime()` is a PHP function, not a MySQL function.

Comment: ok, what should i use then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM USERS 
WHERE nickname = '$nickname' 
AND COLUMNTIME < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
;
```

Comment: sorry it does not work :S No error given, but the result isnt good.

Comment: I've updated the query! Didn't see it was a timestamp (i do think timestamp and datetime comparisons are possible in MySQL)